# SQL: Get first row column value is not empty, else use second row column

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with two type of scenario below:

Scenario A: Active employee has one row of `DateJoin` data

```
----     ----        ----
Name     Column      Value
----     ----        ----
Emp A    DateJoin    20190701
```

Scenario B: Resigned employee will has its `DateJoin` data empty, inserted new row call `ResignDate`

```
----     ----        ----
Name     Column      Value
----     ----        ----
Emp A    DateJoin    NULL
Emp A    ResignDate  20190702
```

For first scenario, it's straight forward, I just need to get the value of the row. But for second scenario, `DateJoin` will be empty so I must get `ResignDate` as the value.

I'm trying to achieve this with below query (not a working query):

```
SELECT e.Name, 
-- Not working due to syntax error in CASE
CASE WHEN LEN(SELECT Value FROM ed WHERE Column = 'DateJoin') > 0
    THEN SELECT Value FROM ed WHERE Column = 'DateJoin'
    ELSE SELECT Value FROM ed WHERE Column = 'ResignDate'
END AS EmpDate
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN employee_date ed ON e.Name = ed.Name
```

How do I achieve above with CASE? Or is there any better idea to achieve it?

Comment: So you have a table with three columns name , date join , resign date. if that's the case you can simply do                                                          SELECT name
  , CASE WHEN resigndate IS NULL THEN date_join ELSE resigndate END AS empdate  FROM table

Comment: @Taps DateJoin & ResignDate are not column name, they are value under "Column". The table structure columns are: Name, Column and Value

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the data - I came up with below that you can use as the starting point

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t 

SELECT 'emp A' AS [name] , 'datejoin' AS col , CAST('20190701' AS DATE) AS value 
INTO #t 

INSERT INTO #t 
SELECT 
'emp B',    
'datejoin', 
NULL 

INSERT INTO #t 
SELECT 
'emp B',    
'Resign',   
'20190703'


SELECT name  ,  MAX(value) AS date 
 FROM #t GROUP BY name



 ;WITH temp AS (
 SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value DESC )  AS rn FROM #t 
 )
 SELECT  temp.name  , temp.col  , temp.value 
 FROM temp 

 WHERE rn = 1
```